# How to acces array of structures in structure Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, structure

I have the following stucture:

```
struct Points : Codable {
    var name : String?
    var interests : [Interests]
    
    ///How do i get string or array of string that is equal to all interests
    
    var allInterestText : String ///???
}

struct Interests : Codable {
    var interest : Interest?
}

struct Interest : Codable{
    var name : String?
}
```

I've been trying to achieve that, but all my attempts have failed.

Comment: `var allInterests: String { interests.joined(separator: ",") }`

Comment: Well which one is it, an array of strings or a single string?

Comment: Referencing instance method 'joined(separator:)' on 'BidirectionalCollection' requires the types 'Interests' and 'String' be equivalent

Comment: anything, could be both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for a single String:

```
struct Points {

    // ...

    var allInterestText: String {
        interests.compactMap { $0.interest?.name }.joined(separator: " ")
    }
}
```

if you decide you want an Array instead, simple change the type and remove the `.joined()`